# UpdatePanel ASyncPostBack troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am having some problems using UpdatePanels in my C#/ASP.NET application.
I shall post my code first, and then explain my problem.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSavedAddresses" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="">Choose from your saved addresses: </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlAddress" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlSavedAddresses" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
 <ContentTemplate>
 <div>
    <div class="minWidth490 topMargin10">
        <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="buildingName">Building Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txtBuildingName" CssClass="short" ToolTip="Enter your house name here" />
        </div>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The above is my .ascx file file.

```
this.ddlSavedAddresses.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlSavedAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged);

void ddlSavedAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // in my code, I have a breakpoint in this method, which is being hit
    this.txtBuildingName.Text = "FOO";
}
```

My actual code has more fields than this (I'm sure you gathered that) however it is simply more of the same.

As stated above, the event is firing, and any breakpoints I set in the ddlSavedAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged are being hit.

I also put a quickwatch on the .Text value of this.txtBuidlingName and it appears to be "FOO" as expected, however, the actual value of the textbox that the web page has rendered remains blank.

This is my issue.  No matter what, the value remains blank.  If I fire the event multiple times (by changing the DropDownList's SelectedIndex), it simply fills each field in the  with a ',' for every event I fire.

I believe I am being short sighted and this is something miniscule, however, I am at a loss and would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Just a test: add `upnlAddress.Update();` at the end of your SelectedIndexChanged event. Tell us if it works that way. Another thing: if you change the selected items 5 times, `txtBuildingName.Text` will be ",,,,," or just ","?

Comment: @daniloquio - If I fire the event 5 times then txtBuildingName.Text will contain ",,,,,".  One for each event.

Comment: Do you have any javascript that might be changing the value of a textbox?

Comment: Ok, so now I feel like I should be back in school.  pnlAddress.Update with UpdateMode="Conditional" has worked as gives the desired behaviour.

Thank you very much daniloquio.

Comment: @user1515466 I'm glad your problem is solved. I'll post my comment as an answer then. If you want, you can mark my answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please rephrase your question's title to avoid tags and common words, be specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Imported from the comments section**

1. Add `upnlAddress.Update();` at the end of your SelectedIndexChanged event.
2. Add `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to your UpdatePanel definition.

Comment: Can I also add that the ','s being added to the text fields were due to the fact that I had multiple of these UserControls on the same page, but had not sent the ClientIdMode of the control to ClientIdMode.AutoId.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you need call Update method of your updatepanel.
try this :

```
void ddlSavedAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    this.txtBuildingName.Text = "FOO";
     upnlAddress.Update();
}
```